# How to make XamarinStudio generate object files into a seperate directory?

Tags: msbuild, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xbuild

Let's take this one by example. I'm developing on linux and using XamarinStudio for all of my .NET projects. I like it more than having VisualStudio running in the virtual machine. I have a solution that has several projects in it, that looks like this:

```
/Solution
/Solution/Project1 -> project number 1
/Solution/Project2 -> project number 2
/Solution/Project3 -> project number 3
/Solution/Output   -> output folder for all projects
/Solution/Temp     -> temporary files for all projects
```

I'm able to set the output directory for all projects, but I don't know how to set projects to generate temporary files to the Temp folder. Right now temporary files are generated into /Solution/ProjectX/obj/x86/Debug/ and /Solution/ProjectX/obj/x86/Debug/. How can I change it? I couldn't find the way to set it in the project/solution properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MSBuild to build your projects from within Xamarin Studio then you can use the **IntermediateOutputPath** element in the project file (.csproj) to override the default directory where obj files are stored.

```
<IntermediateOutputPath>..\Temp\ProjectX\obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
```

You can change where obj files are saved by editing the project file (.csproj) in a text editor and adding the IntermediateOutputPath so it points to your temp directory.  You will probably want to have different directories for each project.

I tried this with Xamarin Studio 5.7 with Mono 3.12 on the Mac and it seems to work. This should also work with Visual Studio.